# Well definition of algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose we have unitary $\mathbb{K}$-algebras $A,B$ and $A$ is generated by $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$. Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be an unitary algebra homomorphism satisfying $f(a_i) = b_i$ where $b_i$ are any elements of $B$. When is $f$ well defined?

---

I know that $f$ does not have to be well defined:

Suppose $A = \{a+eb: a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ where $ee=0$. So $A$ is generated $\{1,e\}$

$B = \mathbb{R}$

$f(1) = 1,
f(e) = 1 $

than $0 = f(ee) = f(e)f(e) = 1 \cdot 1 = 1$

---

So I guess that a sufficient condition for $f$ to be well defined is:

if there are $i,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $r_i\in \mathbb{K}$ such that $a_i a_j =\sum_{k=1}^n r_k a_k$ then $f(a_i)f( a_j) =r f(\sum_{k=1}^n r_k a_k)$ must hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $K$-algebra $A$ has generators $a_1,...,a_r$, a $K$-algebras homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ with $f(a_i)=b_i$ exists if and only if the following condition is satisfied:

For every $P(X)\in K[X_1,...,X_r]$ such that $P(a_1,...,a_r)=0$, one has $P(b_1,...,b_r)=0$.

Sometimes, it is easier to use other informations, even when you have explicit generators. For instance, in your case you are considering an homomorphism
$$
f:A=\frac{\Bbb R[x]}{(x^2)}\longrightarrow B=\Bbb R
$$
In this case the target ring is exactly the algebra $K=\Bbb R$, so $f$ is either the null map or surjective. In the latter case, its kernel must be a maximal ideal of which there's only one, namely the ideal $Ax$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!